# alsamixer not incrementing volume at proper interval

Tags: ubuntu, alsa

I am trying to use amixer to change the volume of the speaker on my computer at an incremental rate. The command below successfully changes the master volume of my speaker, but not at a consistant 5%. When the volume is close to 100%, it will increment at about 15%, but when it is close to 0 it will increment by less than 5%. Why is this an how can I fix it?

```
amixer -q sset -c 1 Master 5%+ unmute
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Master` mixer control is whatever is implemented by your hardware.

When you tell `amixer` to increment by 5 %, it just searches for some supported value that is nearest to what you want.

Please note that the raw mixer values do not necessarily correspond to actual loudness as you perceive it, i.e., 5 % might not be the same relative change in loudness over the entire range. If your hardware provides information about the mapping of mixer values to dB values, you can try to get consistent loudness changes with the `-M` parameter.